# Movimentação objeto

Tags: python, pygame

Eu estaria criando um jogo para um trabalho de faculdade, porem estou com algumas dificuldades, entre elas, uma na qual não consigo fazer com que o personagem se movimente para cima nem para baixo, somente para os lados, me acusando este erro:

> File "C:/Users/estima/Desktop/jogo python/RPG.py", line 48, in rpg
>       jogador.rect.down += jogador.velocidade AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'down'`

na qual não estou conseguindo sanar, alguma ideia ?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

largura = 670
altura = 690

class Guerreiro (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.guerreiro = pygame.image.load('imagem/solo.png')

        self.rect = self.guerreiro.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = largura / 2
        self.rect.centery = altura / 2

        self.vida = True
        self.velocidade = 20


    def colocar (self, superficie):
        superficie.blit(self.guerreiro, self.rect)


def rpg():
    pygame.init()
    tela = pygame.display.set_mode((largura,altura))
    pygame.display.set_caption("RPG do SI")


    jogador = Guerreiro()
    imagemFundo = pygame.image.load('imagem/mapa.png')
    jogando = True

    while True:
        for evento in pygame.event.get():
            if evento.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if evento.key == K_LEFT:
                    jogador.rect.left -= jogador.velocidade

                if evento.key == K_RIGHT:
                    jogador.rect.right += jogador.velocidade

                if evento.key == K_DOWN:
                    jogador.rect.down += jogador.velocidade

        tela.blit(imagemFundo,(0,0))
        jogador.colocar(tela)
        pygame.display.update()

rpg()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `Rect` não possui os atributos `up` e `down`, mas possui `top` e `bottom`.

Mude seu código para:

```
if evento.key == K_DOWN:
    jogador.rect.bottom += jogador.velocidade
```

que vai funcionar.